# what is the difference between O(nk) and O(n+k) in time complexity?

Tags: algorithm, time, complexity-theory

In big O notation of time complexity in algorithmic analysis, when an algorithm depends on n and k, what is the difference between these two notations. 
Also pls help in the notation to use if there is a nested loop with outer loop running n times and inner loop running k times ?

Answer (score 28):

O(nk):

```
for( i=0; i<n; i++ ) {
   for( j=0; j<k; j++ )
   {}
}
```

O(n+k):

```
for( i=0; i<n; i++ )
{}

for( j=0; j<k; j++ )
{}
```

Comment: On modern compilers I would expect both of them to be O(1) ;)

Comment: @user4235730 well, it pretty much depends on types of i and j :-)

Answer (score 4):

O(n+k) indicates a linear growth rate in the larger of *n* or *k*. Suppose *n* is greater. Then

```
n + k <= n + n = 2n = O(n)
```

If *n* is smaller, though, then

```
n + k <= k + k = 2k = O(k).
```

Whether or not *n* is the larger, it's always true that

```
n + k = O(n+k)
```

so this notation helps hide that uncertainty. Such two-variable notation is useful for graph algorithms, using *n* for the number of vertices and *m* for the number of edges. You can write one expression, O(n + m), to indicate that the algorithm is O(n) for sparse graphs (m = Theta(n)) but slower for more dense graphs (e.g., O(n^2) if m = Theta(n^2)).

For the second question, it's just simple arithmetic. You iterate the inner loop k times on the first iteration of the outer loop, k times for the second, etc, for a total of k+k+...+k = n*k total operations, which is O(nk).

Comment: It's not linear growth in the larger of n and k. It's linear growth in both n and k.  If n is greater than k, but k gets larger, the runtime of the algorithm still grows linearly with k.

Comment: Well, you can ignore `k` altogether as long as k = O(n). Only when k = omega(n) do O(n) and O(n+k) mean different things.

Comment: (I am thinking in terms of algorithm analyasis, though, where `n` and `k` are "fixed" in the sense that they describe the input to a particular algorithm, and O(n+k) describes the running time of the algorithm on an input of that size. My interpretation probably does not hold up well in a more purely mathematical sense of the notation.)

Comment: @chepner-It is very bad idea to measure an independent parameter with other unrelated parameter---you shouldn't mention about the relation between n and k for a question like this. Though,I agree that in relating cases your description stays fit!

Answer (score 2):

It should be clear that these are different since, for example if n=k:

O(nk)=O(nn)=O(n^2)

O(n+k)=O(2n)=O(n)

Comment: Thanks.. if the case is O(n+k) how will the loop be? Is it a nested loop or two loops in a row..

Comment: O(n+k) would reflect the total running time of two sequential loops, rather than nested loops, where the first one has n iterations and the second loop has k iterations.

Answer (score 1):

O(nk) means the time it takes is proportional to `n * k`.  O(n+k) means the time it takes is proportional to `n + k`.  It's exactly what it seems like.  You will need to be more specific in your question about what you don't understand.

In your case, the algorithm's runtime is O(nk) because the inner loop runs a total of `n * k` times.

Comment: @GobiKrishnan O(nk) is the same thing as O(n*k) It's just two different ways of writing multiplication...,

Answer (score -1):

Saying that function *f(n)* is *O(g(n))* means that there exists some constant q such that for all values of *n* which are no less than one, *f(n)* will be no greater than *q g(n)*.

Conversely, saying that function *f(x,y)* is *O(g(x,y))* means that there exists some constant q such that for all values of *x* and *y* which are no less than one, *f(x,y)* will be no greater than *q g(x,y)*.

If *k* is a constant, then both values above are equivalent to *O(n)* since for any value of *k*, and for any *n* which is no less than one, if one sets *q* equal to *(k+1)*, then neither *nk* nor *n+k* will exceed *qn* [i.e. *(k+1)n*] for any value of *n* which is no less than one.

If *k* and *n* are both fully-independent variables, then O(nk) is irreducible; O(n+k) will be O(max(n,k)), since if one sets *q* equal to 2, q(max(n,k)) [i.e. 2max(n,k)] will be greater than or equal to n+k for all values of *n* and *k* which are no less than one.

Comment: In this case, I don't think k is taken to be a constant.

Comment: Even in case of fully independent variables, the complexity would remain O(n+k). Your explanation is wrong and is absurd in the last paragraph! It won't be O(max(n+k)) as two unrelated variables can't compared for maximum value!!!

Comment: @shekharsuman: Fixed to O(max(n,k)). Why can't two unrelated variables be compared for maximum value?  The function max(x,y) is equal to x when x>=y, and is equal to y when y>=x.

Comment: @supercat-Only when x and y are kinda related then only we find maximum! Please tell me the maximum of [max(x^2,y^3)] given that x and y are unrelated totally! You might have got the reason for why it can't be so!

Comment: The value of the described function is x^2 for values of x and y such that x^2 >= y^3, and y^3 for values such that y^3 > x^2.  In some cases it may be easier to work with the sum x+y, but in others it may be easier to show that one will exceed the other in all scenarios of interest [in which case one may ignore the lower value].