# Compare two arrays and return the index of the first appearence

Tags: arrays, time-complexity, complexity-theory

I have a task to do, and I was thinking about it, but I dont come up with the right answer.

> In a language of your choosing, write a function that gets a string named str and a string named set.
>
> The function will return the index of the first appearance of any char from set in str.
>
> For example:
> str = "hellohellohellohelloistom!"
> set = "t98765!"
>
> The function will return 22 (index of '5' in str).
> Make sure that time complexity is not larger than the length of both strings - O(m+n)
> Assume that the string only contains ASCII characters.

I was thinking about it and I thought about doing it with divide and conquer. I have a base case that is always O(1) and the I divide the problem in smaller problems until I get the answer. The problem is that with that solution the complexity will be O(log n).

The other approax I thought was to make a Set. But I still don't really know how to approach this problem. Any ideas??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since all the strings involved contain only ASCII characters then using `constant memory` this can be solved in `O(LengthOf(str) + LengthOf(set))`.

Here is the code in "C" Language:

```
//ReturnValues:
//-1 : if no occurrence of any character of set is found in str
//value >=0 : index of character in str.
int FindFirstOccurenceOfAnyCharacterInSet(const char *str, const char *set, int *index_of_set)
{
    char hash[256];
    int i = 0;
    while(i < 256)
    {
        hash[i] = -1;
        ++i; 
    }
    i = 0;
    while(set[i] != '\0')    
    {
        hash[set[i]] = i;
        ++i;
    }
    i = 0;
    while(str[i] != '\0')
    {
        if(hash[str[i]] != -1)
        {
            *index_of_set = hash[str[i]];
            return i;
        }
        ++i;
    }
    *index_of_set = -1;
    return -1;
}
```

Logic works by recording the position/indexes (which are >=0) of all the characters of `set` in `hash` table and then parsing `str` and checking whether the current character of `str` is present in `hash` table.

`index_of_set` will also report the index of character in `set` which is found in `str`. If `index_of_set = -1` then no occurrence was found.

Comment: That was the key!! Thanks!

Comment: `hash` table is populated with `-1` because we are trying to store the `indexes` in table and all the valid indexes are always `>=0`. So if we want to check whether any `str[i]` is present in table then we can directly jump to location (a location whose value is str[i]) in table and if the value at that location is `-1` then will specify that there is no index/character of `set` stored at that location.

Comment: I got it, but then in the second while I shoukd compare it with -1, no with 0? If i compare it with 0, then its going to continue even if the set is not that long.

Comment: `while(set[i] != '\0')`  and `while(str[i] != '\0')` will help just parse the string or parse all the characters in string. All valid C-Strings end with `NULL '\0'` character. We do not want to go ahead of `{end of string} which is specified by `{NULL '\0'}` character. `set = "t98765!"` will be stored in memory as follows: `set[0]='t', s[1]='9', ....set[6]='!', set[7]='\0'`. So we just want to consider character from `0 to 6` and we know that when we will encounter '\0'  character at an index then that will mark as end of string.

Answer (score 2):

This program is written in Swift

```
let str = "hellohellohellohelloistom!"
let set = "t98765!"

func findFirstAppearance(str : String , set : String) -> Int? {
    var index : Int?

mainLoop: for setCharacter in set.characters{

    for (indexOfChar,strCharacter) in str.characters.enumerate(){

        if strCharacter == setCharacter{
        index = indexOfChar
            break mainLoop
        }
    }

}

return index
}

print(findFirstAppearance(str, set: set))
print(findFirstAppearance("helloWorld", set: "546Wo"))
```

Or another solution with less time consuming

```
let str = "hellohellohellohelloistom!"
let set = "t98765!"

func findFirstAppearance(str : String , set : String) -> Int? {
    var index : Int?

    mainLoop: for setCharacter in set.characters{

        if let range = str.rangeOfString(String(setCharacter)){

            index = str.startIndex.distanceTo(range.startIndex)

            break
        }

    }

    return index
}

print(findFirstAppearance(str, set: set))
print(findFirstAppearance("helloWorld", set: "546Wo"))
```

Note :

1. if any character is not found then it will return nil
2. it's case sensitive comparison

Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: But in the answer you mark you are using two for loops. That means the complexity of the solution is O(n2), or Im worng?

Comment: Exactly, thats the problem. I need the complexity to be O(m+n). Thats the problem. Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your help Govind, but I think Im still in the same situation, better but not perfect :) haha. As we are using a For loop, then the complexity will be O(n), and I need it to be O(m+n). Thats why I thought about a different strategy.. Understand?

Comment: Your welcome and plz let me know  (post answer) if u found a perfect solution. :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help!!

Here is also the code in C#.

Cheers,

```
public static int FindFirstOccurenceOfAnyCharacterInSet(string str, string set)
    {
        var hash = new int[256];
        int i = 0;
        while (i < 256)
        {
            hash[i] = -1;
            ++i;
        }
        i = 0;
        do
        {
            hash[set[i]] = i;
            ++i;
        } while (set[i] != '\0' && i < set.Length - 1);
        i = 0;
        while (str[i] != '\0')
        {
            if (hash[str[i]] != -1)
            {
                return i;
            }
            ++i;
        }
        return -1;
    }
```

Comment: Nice but i don't think so it's perfect answer because it uses three loops for checking and also more complex :)

Comment: I will make it perfect and edited here. I was checking your answer again, and the second one could be good as well. The problem with the first answer was that as you were using two for looks (one inside the other) the complexity wasn't O(n+m).                                                                              [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27301734/4300137) Check this answer, I understood it very well! thanks!!